# How can I access a Vim process after closing its terminal on macOS?

Tags: command-line, terminal, process, osx, vim

This what I get when I run the `ps` command:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
14777 ttys000    0:00.25 -bash
19716 ttys000    0:00.15 vi templates/base.html
 8240 ttys001    0:00.11 -bash
 8284 ttys002    0:00.04 -bash
14832 ttys004    0:00.06 -bash
17504 ttys004    0:00.15 python ./app.py
17505 ttys004    1:05.52 /Users/Utka/virtualenv/bin/python ./app.py
19732 ttys005    0:00.02 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp MrDifferent
19734 ttys005    0:00.01 -bash
```

I accidently closed the terminal by hitting Cmd+W on my Mac. When I open my terminal again it shows up in the `ps` list. I want to resume working on it.

I want to reactivate the vim process i.e.19716 to edit. What command do I need to run to reopen that particular vim process?

Comment: How did you make it "inactive"?

Comment: I accidently closed the terminal by hitting Cmd+W on my Mac. When I open my terminal again it shows up in the **ps** list. I want to resume working on it.

Answer (score 3):

Go back in the directory your `base.html` is located, look for a file named `.base.html.swp`. If it does exist, then, you should be able to run `vi -r base.html` and recover the last state of your file.

```
$ ls -a | grep base
base.html
.base.html.swp
$ kill 19716 #your vim process
$ vi -r base.html
[ save your changes, quit ]
$ rm -f .base.html.swp
```

Comment: Yeah, there is this workaround and I always do this only. But, I wanted to know if there is any one command solution for this, like `$ fg 19716` as the vim with base.html file open is still showing up in the ps command's list. I was wondering if there is a way to resume that same state of vim with that file.

Comment: job control is limited to your shell, you can't recover a process from an other terminal. An alternative here may be to use something like `tmux` or `screen` logging into your servers: being able to keep your console alive between ssh sessions, you would be able to preserve access to your child processes.

Answer (score 1):

short: no, you can't

long: actually vi probably wouldn't be running unless its *parent* process was not directly the shell.  You can see what is running using `ps -efl`, and following the `PPID` to `PID` data.

However, it is not a *job* that you can switch into the foreground using `fg`.  That only works for subprocesses of your current shell.

You can *inspect* the process using `gdb` or `dtrace`, but have lost control over the process.